# Why not connected with peer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multipeer-connectivity

I want to build a send files application.
It has a **Friends** function.

If I find a **friend**, I will connect to them.

There will be **'Friends'** and there will be **'Strangers'**

If I find a stranger Peer, I will save it to `NSMutableArray *strangerPeers`

When I want a stranger to become a friend,

I use `browser` invitation them.

The question was born there.

```
/* So that's how I connect. */
MCPeerID *strangerPeer = [self strangerPeerWithStrangerName:newFriend];
MCSession  *session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.sharerPeer
                                         securityIdentity:nil
                                     encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionNone];
[session setDelegate:self];
[self.sessions addObject:session];
[self.browser invitePeer:strangerPeer
               toSession:session
             withContext:nil
                 timeout:10];
```

It's the same code I used to connect to **Friend**.

```
- (void)  browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser
        foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)info {
  NSLog(@"found user: %@", peerID.displayName);
  if ([self isFriend:peerID.displayName]) {
    WSConnecting *newConn = [WSConnecting new];
    [newConn setPeer:peerID];
    [self.friendsConnectings addObject:newConn];
    if ([self.sharerName compare:peerID.displayName] == NSOrderedDescending) {
      MCSession *session = [self availableSession];
      [newConn setSession:session];
      [browser invitePeer:peerID toSession:session withContext:nil timeout:10];
    }
  } else {
    [self.strangersPeerID addObject:peerID];
    NSLog(@"self.strangersPeerID.count: %lu", self.strangersPeerID.count);
    WorkSharerUser *stranger = [WorkSharerUser userWithName:peerID.displayName
                                                    picture:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameUser]
                                           sharerFolderPath:nil
                                                   isFriend:NO];
    [self.strangers addObject:stranger];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self.delegate reloadUsers];
    });
  }
}
```

Just found a friend immediately connected to them; Found a stranger save this peet to `NSMutableArray *strangerPeers`.

But when I invite peer of stranger,

It's can't connected, will stop on state `MCSessionStateConnecting`

```
- (void)strangerDidBecameFriend:(NSString *)newFriend {
  MCPeerID *strangerPeer = [self strangerPeerWithStrangerName:newFriend];
  if (strangerPeer) {
    MCSession  *session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.sharerPeer
                                         securityIdentity:nil
                                     encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionNone];
    [session setDelegate:self];
    [self.sessions addObject:session];
    [self.browser invitePeer:strangerPeer toSession:session withContext:nil timeout:10];
  }
}
```

Comment: "There will be 'Friends' and there will be 'Strangers'"  You are the only one who knows what that means.

Comment: obviously "Friend" is a flag that allows more rights than all other. The split in two Arrays makes not much sense because in your model, a stranger can be a friend and vice versa and the interaction of both is a perfect target to attack your code..

Comment: If I find any users (friends and strangers), I will connect them first.
Once I connect to them, I will distinguish which connections can send files.
For adding strangers as friends, I send a specific packet instead of using ```browser```. Thanks!!